# Extra form padding in Firefox but not Safari

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to display a few elements inline. Two are `<a href>` and one is a `<form>`. For some reason Safari renders everything inline and uniform. However, Firefox seems to add padding to the `<form>`.

Here's how it renders in Safari:

[image: Safari]

Here's how it renders in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

My code can be found in the jsFiddle below. Does anyone know what the problem is? I'd like to fix this in Firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/feBvz/

Comment: Hmmm what if you tried using a `<button type="submit">` element instead?

Comment: Well I'm using the form for my Rails app and I tried implementing `button_to` but need to figure out how to do so while including a hidden field. That's why I wanted to see if I could fix it with CSS.

Comment: May be because you used em units in padding I found these type of error because my web page displayed differently in google chrome , IE and firefox when i used padding-left 20 em so then I used 40 px instead of em units and it worked on all browsers so My helpful suggestion is to use px always and em or pt units only for font-size

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="button white" name="commit" title="Hover" type="submit" value="+">+</button>
```

This looks ok in my browsers. Might not solve your problem due to the fact that you said you had to use a specific rails function.

Another solution might be to use Uniform js, which gives you more specific control of the styling of input elements.
[Uniform js](http://uniformjs.com/)!